# 「あさってが日曜日は暇ですか。」どうして「が」っていう助詞が出ますか

Tags: grammar, particle-が

‎今日本語の教科書を勉強して、次の文が出ました。

> あさって**が**日曜日は暇ですか。

どうして「が」っていう助詞が出ますか。自分に次の文の方が意味がある。

> あさって**の**日曜日は暇ですか。

Comment: 「あさっての日曜日は暇ですか」sounds perfect to me.

Comment: `あさってが日曜日は暇ですか。` は間違いだと思います。何という教科書ですか？

Answer (score 1):

おっしゃる通り、その教科書に記載の文では何を言いたいのかわかりません。

Aaronさんが添削された下記の文なら、意味がとおります。

> あさっての日曜日は暇ですか。

下記のように言うこともありますよ。

> あさっては日曜日ですが、暇ですか。